# How to run CSS animation while elements are added to page?

Tags: css, angular

I have noticed that when angular updates a page by adding a lot of elements even CSS animations stop running. I created a stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fefvpa to highlight the issue. When you hit the "Add Elements" button, the red square stops moving for about half a second. What can I do to circumvent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really avoid that.

You're appending a thousand children, which is a rather important process.

This kind of operation should be done in small chunks, [something like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwjqm3?file=src/app/components/timeLine.component.ts).

Javascript is a monothread script language, which means most of the operations are blocking. When you do them one by one, then sure, it's pretty. But when you run a thousand operations at the same time (well, one after the other without any break), you face this kind of issues. Especially with DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

One solution i can think of that might help you is to use `transform: translateX` in the animation instead of `left`.

your anim would look like

```
@keyframes mymove {
  from {transform: translateX(0)}
  to {transform: translateX(400px)}
}
```

You can also add `transform:translateZ(0)` to the `#box` itself

The animation will use less ' GPU ' and by adding `transform:translateZ(0)`  you will also make the browser use more GPU for that animation. So it might run smoother.

I tested it on my pc and it doesn't ' freeze ' anymore when adding items.

Comment: @ManishKhedekar thank you, but why do you share a link to my SO profile ? :)

Comment: I was adding @Mihai T. ;)